# Can I reserve another port for my app on bluemix?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ibm-cloud

I am writing a node.js express app, which has a webserver to serve routes:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log("app is listening on port: " + (process.env.PORT || 3000));
  console.log("\n");
});
```

I am also wanting to "stream" data to my page using socket.io. I *think* I need to have that read off a separate port number. I've done this which runs locally just fine:

```
var server = require('http').Server();
var Server = require('socket.io');
var io = Server(8080);
```

So my question is, since I can't use the same port (process.env.PORT) can I get a different secondary port number from bluemix to use? Or what's the right this to do exactly?

Answer (score 4):

You can use http and websocket on the same port.

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
...
io.listen(app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
    console.log("server starting on port " + process.env.PORT);
}));
```